# Error '-2147021892 (80070bbc)' when opening file on network

Tags: excel, vba

Using vba code I am opening an excel file from Excel on a network drive. The error returns to the following line of code. The file that contains the vba code is located on a VM on the server.
It suddenly stopped working a couple of days ago (I suspect some automatic windows update or virus software update which I cannot roll back anyway.)

The error points to the following line of code: 
Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)

The file is not corrupted because I can open it fine with my computer (the one with the vba and the one on the network).
I also have several older backup copies of this file that used to work and now have the same error message.

Here is the code in the context:

```
    Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Local_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Target_Path As String

    Target_Path = "U:\DATABASES\Prod Sched\PlannedPallets.xls"
    Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)
    Set Local_Workbook = ThisWorkbook

    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets("PlannedPallets").Range("A1:CZ50")
    Local_Workbook.Sheets("PlannedPallets").Range("A1:CZ50") = Target_Data
    Local_Workbook.Sheets("Criteria").Range("V25") = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    '''''Close Target Workbook
    Local_Workbook.Save
    ' Target_Workbook.Save
    Target_Workbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: `Windows Error 0xBBC (3004) An AddJob call was not issued.` This is a printer subsystem error. You can see an answer here on how to decode errors https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e809a255-881d-4308-afb5-770454feb615/vbscript-error-number-conversion?forum=scripting.

Comment: From *Winerror.h*. `//Win32 Spooler Error codes//
//3000 to 3049//` and `// MessageId: ERROR_SPL_NO_ADDJOB
// MessageText:
// An AddJob call was not issued.
#define ERROR_SPL_NO_ADDJOB              3004L`

Comment: Is the file in a trusted location? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973736

Comment: @ACatInLove, the error is 0x80070bbc, not just 0xBBC

Comment: I gave you a link on how to decode errors. 0x8007nnnn contain a Win32 error. So 0x80070bbc = 0xbbc.

Comment: Change the default printer in Excel and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped to open WB readonly, then save it as ...

Instead of:

```
Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)
```

Use:

```
Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path, ReadOnly:=True)
```